# How to make an image a qualified mask candidate in itext?

Tags: image, itext, mask, clipping

I'm intended to mask an image,for example, *A.jpg* using another local image *B.jpg* in **itext**, and firstly I try to make the imageB a mask directly and I got the DocumentException: This image cannot be an image mask,so I try to make *B.jpg* a **rawimage**  Here are my codes:

```
RandomAccessFile rf = new RandomAccessFile("B.jpg", "rw");
        int size = (int)rf.length();
        byte imagedata[] = new byte[size];
        rf.readFully(data);
        rf.close();
Image mask = Image.getInstance("B.jpg");
        int w =(int) Math.ceil(mask.getWidth());
        int h =(int) Math.ceil(mask.getHeight()); 
mask = Image.getInstance(w,h,1,1,data); 
mask.makemask();
```

I got the **byte[]** data from *B.jpg* and try to reconstruct the *B.jpg*,but it doesn't work I can't get the correct image,so how can I make the image a qualified image mask?Is there any other way to mask an image from another image in itext?It looks like how to clip image but the mask sharp can be quite complex,not only rectangles or circles you can draw with ContentByte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [MakeJpgMask](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/MakeJpgMask) example. In this example, I took two normal JPG files and I used one as mask for the other, resulting in a rather spooky PDF: [jpg_mask.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/jpg_mask.pdf)

[image]

To achieve this, I needed to change one colored JPEG into a black and white image:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Image image = Image.getInstance(IMAGE);
    Image mask = makeBlackAndWhitePng(MASK);
    mask.makeMask();
    image.setImageMask(mask);
    image.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    document.add(image);
    document.close();
}

public static Image makeBlackAndWhitePng(String image) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(image));
    BufferedImage newBi = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
    newBi.getGraphics().drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(newBi, "png", baos);
    return Image.getInstance(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

As you can see, we have converted berlin2013.jpg into a black and white image and we have used this as a mask for the colored javaone2013.jpg image.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Lowagie, that helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Image masks must be monochrome or grayscale, color won't do.